# CSS - "The sum of the horizontal components of a block-level element box always equals the width of the parent?"

Tags: css, w3c, specifications

I am reading CSS The Definitive Guide by Eric Meyer. On page 162, it says the following:

> Almost as simple is the rule that says that the sum of the horizontal components of a block-level element box in the normal flow always equals the width of the parent.

I find a similar passage in the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#block-level-elements) specification:

> The horizontal position and size of a non-floating, block-level element is determined by seven properties: 'margin-left', 'border-left', 'padding-left', 'width', 'padding-right', 'border-right' and 'margin-right'. The sum of these seven is always equal to the 'width' of the parent element.

However, I can think of a very simple case where the above rule does not hold true.

```
# HTML
<div><p>This is a paragraph.</p></div>

# CSS
div { width: 200px; }
p { width: 300px; }
```

Obviously I could set `overflow` to contain the p element. However I just want to know am I interpreting the rule incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't read the old specifications of CSS1, except for curiosity, as you can read in the red box on the page you linked. CSS2.1 defines well this situation: in [paragraph 10.3.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) you can read that such configuration is called *over-constrained*, and one horizontal margin is ignored and set to a value in order to make the equality true. The right one will be choose if the writing mode is left to right, otherwise it'll be the left one.

Comment: I think you're correct that the right margin is being set to negative margin to make the equality true. I was just confused because in Chrome inspector it doesn't say that. Have no idea why.

Comment: @ctcworks that's because Chrome and every other developing tool I know show you the *computed value*, but if you read [paragraph 10.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) you'll notice that it isn't changed, it's the *used value* that changes and for the moment no browser implements the [API that allows to get it](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#dom-getstyleutils-usedstyle).

Comment: Thank you! You have saved me tons of time!

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that the "sub element at 100% always equals the width of the parent". Obviously if you set the width to anything smaller/bigger it will differ. But it inherits the same width unless specifically set.